# When trying to stop player from moving after hitting certain object (Blocks) object closest not working

Tags: javascript

This is how my code is laid out, if a player touches an object or moves, the players speed is copied onto the objects therefore giving the illusion of movement. The blocks are objects that stop the player from moving into them, and my function isn't working as intended. The closest block to the player seems to not have the speed copied on, so the illusion is broken as the player looks like he pushes the object. (I'll answer questions if needed)

```
    function blockcollision() {
  for (var u = 0; u < Backgrounds.length; u += 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Blocks.length; i += 1) {
      for (var m = 0; m < Objects.length; m += 1) {
        if (Player[0].collision(Blocks[i])) {
          if (dir === 0) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedY = 1;
            Blocks[i].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
            Objects[m].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
          }
          if (dir === 1) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedY = -1;
            Objects[m].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
            Blocks[i].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
          }
          if (dir === 2) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedX = 1;
            Objects[m].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Blocks[i].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
          }
          if (dir === 3) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedX = -1;
            Objects[m].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Blocks[i].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
          }
          if (dir === 4) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedX = -1;
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedY = -1;
            Objects[m].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Blocks[i].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Objects[m].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
            Blocks[i].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
          }
          if (dir === 5) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedX = -1;
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedY = 1;
            Objects[m].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Blocks[i].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Objects[m].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
            Blocks[i].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
          }
          if (dir === 6) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedX = 1;
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedY = -1;
            Objects[m].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Blocks[i].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Objects[m].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
            Blocks[i].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
          }
          if (dir === 7) {
            playerAllowedMove = false
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedX = 1;
            Backgrounds[u].SpeedY = 1;
            Objects[m].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Blocks[i].SpeedX = Backgrounds[u].SpeedX;
            Objects[m].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
            Blocks[i].SpeedY = Backgrounds[u].SpeedY;
          }
          setTimeout(function() {
            playerAllowedMove = true;
            stopmoving();
          }, 20);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

collision function vvvv

```
this.collision = function(other) {
    var left = this.x;
    var right = this.x + (this.width);
    var bottom = this.y;
    var top = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = other.x;
    var otherright = other.x + (other.width);
    var otherbottom = other.y;
    var othertop = other.y + (other.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((left > otherright) ||
    (right < otherleft) ||
    (bottom > othertop) ||
    (top < otherbottom)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  };
```

Comment: The issue likely resides in `Player.collision(Blocks[i])`, care to post it? I would think setting the speeds on any movement and then stopping on a collision would be a better approach though. As it is now you're checking a lot of stuff you don't need to.

Comment: The collision function detects if a player is not touching the parameter, and if so, returns a Boolean that will do what you request it to do.

Comment: `blockCollision` is but where is `Player.collision`?

Comment: this.collision = function(other) {
    var left = this.x;
    var right = this.x + (this.width);
    var bottom = this.y;
    var top = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = other.x;
    var otherright = other.x + (other.width);
    var otherbottom = other.y;
    var othertop = other.y + (other.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((left > otherright) ||
    (right < otherleft) ||
    (bottom > othertop) ||
    (top < otherbottom)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  };

Comment: please add that to the question and format it.

Comment: Okay hold on a minute. Sorry im pretty new to stack overflow.

Comment: No worries, we all were once.

Comment: I put the collision function up.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an small game which the player (A game object) collides with other game objects (I called them enemies). The method `collidedWith` is what you are interested. You must take into account the position X, Y, Width and Height of the objects (since they are just squares) and make some quick maths.

```
if ((this.x + this.width) > gameObjToBeCollided.x &&
this.x < gameObjToBeCollided.x + gameObjToBeCollided.width &&
(this.y + this.height) > gameObjToBeCollided.y &&
this.y < gameObjToBeCollided.y + gameObjToBeCollided.height){
     //'this' collided with gameObjToBeCollided
}
```

And here is a working example. Of course is not the best but it should give you an idea.

```js
function gameObject(obj) {
    return {
        x: obj.x,
        y: obj.y,
        width: obj.width,
        height: obj.height,
        speedX: obj.speedX,
        speedY: obj.speedY,
        tag: obj.tag,
        render: function() {
            ctx = gameScene.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = obj.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        },
        collidedWith: function(gameObjToBeCollided){
            return ((this.x + this.width) > gameObjToBeCollided.x &&
              this.x < gameObjToBeCollided.x + gameObjToBeCollided.width &&
              (this.y + this.height) > gameObjToBeCollided.y &&
              this.y < gameObjToBeCollided.y + gameObjToBeCollided.height)
        }
    }
}

var player = gameObject(
 {
  x: 0,
  y: 120,
  width: 20,
  height: 10,
  speedX: 3,
  speedY: 0,
  color: "blue",
  tag: "player"
 }
);

var enemy = gameObject(
 {
  x: 200,
  y: 120,
  width: 10,
  height: 80,
  speedX: 0,
  speedY: 0,
  color: "red",
  tag: "enemy"
 }
);

var enemy2 = gameObject(
 {
  x: 300,
  y: 25,
  width: 10,
  height: 80,
  speedX: 0,
  speedY: 0,
  color: "green",
  tag: "enemy"
 }
);

var gameScene = {};
var gameObjects = [player, enemy, enemy2];

function start(){
    gameScene = {
        canvas: document.getElementById("game-scene"),
        refresh: function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
            for (let i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++) {
                gameObjects[i].render();
            }
        },
        stop: function() {
            deathSound.play();
            clearInterval(this.gameLoop);
        }
    }
    gameScene.context= gameScene.canvas.getContext("2d");
    gameScene.gameLoop= setInterval(update, 10);
}  

function update(){
    for (let i=0; i<gameObjects.length; i++){
      let gameObject = gameObjects[i];
      //If the player collided with any enemy game object
      if (gameObject.tag == "enemy" && player.collidedWith(gameObject)){
          player.speedX = 0;
          player.speedY = 0;
      }
      //Update the gameObject position every frame (10 milisecs)
      gameObject.x += gameObject.speedX;
      gameObject.y += gameObject.speedY;
    }
    gameScene.refresh();
}
```

```css
#game-scene {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
    <canvas id="game-scene" width="480" height="270"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: I already have the collision function. I just need help on making the player look like he stops moving when he touches the object.

Comment: There is another property of the object which is speed, just set it to 0 and the player will stop. I updated the code

Comment: No i'm giving the illusion of movement by moving the background.